# How to reduce space between a label/span/p which breaks its text?

Tags: html, css

I have created a label which has some text in it. When I reduce the size of the screen the label breaks into two lines. But the space between 2 lines is too much. How can I reduce it. Below is the code:

[image]

```
<div class="col-xs-12 textAlignCenter fontSize13 fontArialRegular">
                            <span class="wordBreakAll">Location Parameter</span>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove margin and padding of the element with

```
padding:0;
margin: 0; 
line-height: 0;
```

They reset the space after/before the element.